# (key, value) pair using Python Lambdas

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark

I am trying to work on a simple word count problem and trying to figure if that can be done by use of map, filter and reduce exclusively.

Following is an example of an wordRDD(the list used for spark):

```
myLst = ['cats', 'elephants', 'rats', 'rats', 'cats', 'cats']
```

All i need is to count the words and present it in a tuple format:

```
counts = [('cat', 1), ('elephant', 1), ('rat', 1), ('rat', 1), ('cat', 1)]
```

I tried with simple map() and lambdas as:

```
counts = myLst.map(lambdas x: (x, <HERE IS THE PROBLEM>))
```

I might be wrong with the syntax or maybe confused. 
P.S.: This isnt a duplicate questin as rest answers give suggestions using if/else or list comprehensions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How did you get `counts`? your expected result is completely irrelevant to what you want ans your input.

Comment: `lambda` not `lambdas`.

Comment: @Hobbes, thanks for correcting.. I am a java guy so mixed it! :P

Comment: Just to be clear, if you are working on an rdd, you should probably be doing `map` and then `reduceByKey`. `map` is not an eager operation.

Comment: @zengr agreed totally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `map(..)` at all. You can do it with just `reduce(..)`

```
>>> def function(obj, x):
...     obj[x] += 1
...     return obj
...
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(function, myLst, defaultdict(int)).items()
dict_items([('elephants', 1), ('rats', 2), ('cats', 3)])
```

You can then iterate of the result.

---

However, there's a better way of doing it: Look into [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: the problem is, I am working on a Spark project and we are dealing with RDD's  and not lists. Hence Counter arent of much help to us.

Answer (score 1):

Not using a lambda but gets the job done.

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(myLst)
result = list(c.items())
```

And the output:

```
In [21]: result
Out[21]: [('cats', 3), ('rats', 2), ('elephants', 1)]
```

Comment: I agree to this that Counter does help. But unfortunately while dealing with Spark libraries, you deal with RDD's and not with actual lists. Hence no module from collections really help to get the k,v pair.

Comment: Why not convert them into a (k, v) tuple then, before inserting into a counter?

Comment: Why are you calling Counter twice on the list? Why not `for x,y in Counter(myLst).items()`?

Comment: I was just about to say that. You are relying on the underlying order of Counter.keys() and Counter.values() across two objects before zipping them. This can very easily lead to problems. And BTW, there is `.items()` or `iteritems()` on the Counter class.

Comment: ah, my bad. typo due to copy-paste from ipython. Fixed.

Comment: Instead of iterating through the counter, you can just use `c.most_common()` to get `result`

Comment: I guess you can acheive the same (but shorter) result with `result = list(c.items())`

Comment: nice! even better. Didn't realize `Counter` had `items/iteritems`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the full reduce step done for you (which aggregated the counts in SuperSaiyan's answer), you can use map this way:

```
    >>> myLst = ['cats', 'elephants', 'rats', 'rats', 'cats', 'cats']
    >>> counts = list(map(lambda s: (s,1), myLst))
    >>> print(counts)
    [('cats', 1), ('elephants', 1), ('rats', 1), ('rats', 1), ('cats', 1), ('cats', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use map() to get this result:

```
myLst = ['cats', 'elephants', 'rats', 'rats', 'cats', 'cats']

list(map(lambda x : (x,len(x)), myLst))
```

Comment: You know that you can [edit] to improve this broken answering  attempt, don't you? While doing that, please add an explanation of the code you will be showing works and why it helps. Even if you show working code, your answer will otherwise be considered unhelpfully code-only.

Comment: it would help if you explain your code briefly.. also you might notice len(x) doesn't give the counts